# Erro: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando criar uma nova tabela em um DB existente, porém, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'parceria_conta_corrente_ao' that match the referencing column list in
>   the foreign key 'R_795'.

Esta tabela já existe no banco e possui dados:

[image: Tabela existente]

Estou tentando criar a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE parceria_item_resgate_rateio_aux
( 
    id_parceria_item_resgate_rateio_aux int  NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    dt_conta_corrente    DATETIME  NOT NULL ,
    id_periodo           BIGINT  NOT NULL ,
    id_ao                bigint  NOT NULL ,
    id_gr_cliente        int  NOT NULL ,
    id_cliente           BIGINT  NOT NULL ,
    data_importacao_cli_gr_cli DATETIME  NOT NULL ,
    hp2                  varchar(50)  NOT NULL ,
    hp2_filho            varchar(50)  NOT NULL ,
    valor_nc             decimal(18,2)  NULL ,
    datetime_inclusion   datetime  NOT NULL ,
    status               int  NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT XPKparceria_item_resgate_ PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED 
        (id_parceria_item_resgate_rateio_aux ASC, 
        dt_conta_corrente ASC, 
        id_periodo ASC, 
        id_ao ASC, 
        id_gr_cliente ASC, 
        id_cliente ASC, 
        data_importacao_cli_gr_cli ASC, 
        hp2 ASC),
    CONSTRAINT R_795 FOREIGN KEY(dt_conta_corrente, id_periodo, id_ao, id_gr_cliente, id_cliente, data_importacao_cli_gr_cli, hp2) 
        REFERENCES parceria_conta_corrente_ao(dt_conta_corrente, id_periodo, id_ao, id_gr_cliente, id_cliente, data_importacao_cli_gr_cli, hp2)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
go
```

Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta relação de colunas da tabela `parceria_conta_corrente_ao`

```
dt_conta_corrente, id_periodo, id_ao, id_gr_cliente, id_cliente, data_importacao_cli_gr_cli, hp2
```

Não é uma chave primária de `parceria_conta_corrente_ao`.

Aliás, o que você está fazendo pode ser considerado como uma má prática, pois você está tentando amarrar uma série de colunas sem um bom motivo pra isso.

Procure usar apenas uma coluna para definir uma chave primária (e, consequentemente, uma chave estrangeira), pois a causa do problema, num sentido mais amplo, é uma falha de design do seu banco de dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica :)